# Insert data into the table from a form in access 2010

Tags: insert, ms-access-2010

I have a table named stu, it has 3 fields:

> ID(Autonumber) ,
>   SName(Text) ,
>   SNO(Text).

In the form, I just put three textboxes on it(unbound with the stu table) and changed their label name. Then I added an add button. Behind the button, I wrote

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO stu(ID,[SName],[SNO]) VALUES (" & Me.ID & ",'" & Me.SName & "','" & Me.SNO & "')"
```

but nothing happens.
When I bound the `three textboxes` with the `stu table's fields`, stu table actually has new data. But when I tried to refresh the form or go back to previous record, it says:

> "The changes you requested to the table were not successful because
>   they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or
>   relationship."

Comment: Can you give more data: does your project have multiple DBs? Does the DB contain any data, and if so, what? Precisely what data are you testing your program with; what is your SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

Are your IDs unique? if not or if you plan to have duplicated values on ID, please add a forth column (field) to your table and name it something like Primary_Key and set it to autoincrement value.
This way you wont have the problem anymore :)